# Does the relation lim sup$A_n=$lim inf $A_n$ implicates that the sets $A_n$ are necessarily increasing or decreasing ?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given an arbitrary collection $A_n$of sets of the set $E$, does the relation lim sup$A_n=$lim inf $A_n$ implicates that the sets $A_n$ are necessarily increasing or decreasing in the sense of the union or intersection respectively  ? Can you propose a proof ?

I know that the other way round the assertion is true, i.e. if $A_n$ is increasing or decreasing, then lim sup$A_n=$lim inf $A_n=:$lim $A_n.$

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: No.  Perhaps you can find an easy counterexample where each set $A_n$ has only one element.

Comment: Thanks. Given the definition of the intersection, and lim sup and lim inf, does that example mean that for infinitely many indices $A_i=A_j $ ?

Comment: In the case the cardinality of $A_n$ is different of $1$, is the example $A_k, $ such that for all $i, j, A_i=A_j,$  i.e. the constant sequence of sets (or events), an appropriate counterexample ?

Comment: IMHO $A_i = A_j$ does not follow from $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ being equal. Suppose $E=\mathbb R$ and $A_i = \{i\}$. Then every two $A$ sets are distinct and disjoint; but not only disjoint – they are not even 'close' to each other. So there is no accumulation point, hence upper limit and lower limits are both the empty set. However the $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ sequence is neither increasing nor decreasing (unless the empty intersections make the sequence weakly-decreasing, which I'm not aware of...).

Comment: Thanks. I think I meant $A_i=A_j$ for the specific example lim sup and lin inf were not the empty set. Is the constant set of sets an appropriate counterexample ?

Comment: @user249018 Now take $A_i=\{0,i\}$. Then $\limsup A_i=\{0\}=\liminf A_i$ (so not empty).

Answer (score 2):

By definition $\liminf A_n\subseteq\limsup A_n$ so the statement $\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n$ is the same as  $\limsup A_n\subseteq\liminf A_n$.

Actually it states that for every element $x$ for which the set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x\in A_n\}$ is infinite there exists an integer $n_x$ such that $n\geq n_x\implies x\in A_n$.

Observe that for every fixed integer $m$ the sets $A_1,\dots,A_m$ *do not affect* the answer on the question whether this statement is true or false. They "have nothing to say" about the set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x\in A_n\}$ being infinite or not, and they "have nothing to say" about the existence of such integer $n_x$.

This is enough already to conclude that the statement $\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n$ will **not** imply increasing or decreasing of the sets $A_n$.

Comment: Thanks. Can one then conclude that lim $A_n$:=lim sup $A_n=$lim inf $A_n$ is even then defined if $A_n$ is not necessarily increasing or decreasing ?

Comment: @user249018 If $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n$ (or equivalently $\limsup A_n\subseteq\liminf A_n$) then $\lim A_n$ is well defined and equals both. For this it is *not* necessary that $A_n$ are increasing or decreasing.